# Joomla 3 wrong language tag in PHP script

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla multi-language site (FR/EN), all menus and contents work with these two languages. However, in my PHP scripts en-GB is always selected:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
 $language_tag = $lang->getTag();
 echo($language_tag);

return always en-GB ?
```

Although the menus and breadcrumbs follow correctly the selected language in language filter module.

Answer (score 3):

See [getLanguage in JFactory](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getLanguage):

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getName();
```

Once you have the language, you can also retrieve the locale/language code (e.g. `en-US`). Joomla! languages can have multiple locales, so you'll get an array.

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
foreach($lang->getLocale()  as  $locale) {
    echo 'This language supports the locale: ' . $locale;
}
```

If  for some reason, you are only interested in the first locale, you can simply grab the first element. You will probably need an  array, like this:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$locales = $lang->getLocale();
echo 'This language\'s first locale is: ' . $locales[0];
```

If you just want to get the selected language tag (e.g. pt-PT) you can use getTag()

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getTag()
```

### How Joomla! language files work

First of all, let's explain how the language files work in Joomla!. If you're not interested in this, just scroll down for the PHP-code. The basics are that for every language a separate subfolder in the directory language is used. For example:

```
JOOMLA/language/en-GB
JOOMLA/language/de-DE
JOOMLA/language/fr-FR
JOOMLA/language/nl-NL
```

Within this folder, the Joomla! core itself can be translated but third party extensions (components, modules, plugins and templates) as well. By default, Joomla! ships with a core file which is loaded first.

```
JOOMLA/language/en-GB/en-GB.ini
```

After this, the language files belonging to other extensions are loaded. So if you want to make changes to certain translations, editing the core-file makes no sense, because it might be overwritten by other extensions. Also, editing the core-file is a core hack, with which all your changes will be overwritten with the next Joomla! upgrade.

### Using the template to override language strings

Now the trick is that of all extensions (components, modules, plugins, templates) actually the template-code is loaded at last. So if you create a language-file for a specific template, that language-file will have the chance to override any language-strings in previously loaded extensions.

```
JOOMLA/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_mytheme.ini
```

### Overloading a language-file

Still, the language/en-GB folder is part of the core, and messing around in that folder is not what we want. Instead, we use our template to create template override of MVC-based components or modules. So why not create a template-override of a language file?

This is possible by loading a language-file with the following code. This code could be placed somewhere in the **index.php** file of your template - in this case, a template called **mytheme**.

```
$language =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$extension = 'mod_login';
$base_dir = JPATH_SITE;
$language_tag = 'en-GB';
$language->load($extension, $base_dir, $language_tag, true);
```

Or a short-cut version of this is:

```
JFactory::getLanguage()->load('mod_login', JPATH_SITE, 'en-GB', true);
```

This example reloads the English language-file for the Joomla!-login module. But it's not really useful to reload the same language-file twice. But the code shows you that the second argument of the **load()** function is the base-directory where Joomla! will look for the language file.

Now, if we create a file with the following location and change the **$base_dir** to our own template-directory, this will effectively override the previous language-files:

```
$language =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$extension = 'mod_login';
$base_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$language_tag = $language->getTag(); // loads the current language-tag
$language->load($extension, $base_dir, $language_tag, true);
```

The file will be:

```
JOOMLA/templates/mytheme/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_login.ini
```

### Adding your own custom language-file

But the fun doesn't stop here. If you manually load a language-file, it is able to override any language-string in the system. So why not create our own custom language-file instead?

```
$language =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('custom' , dirname(__FILE__), $language->getTag(), true);
```

This code will look in the current directory (your template-directory?) for a folder with the following name, depending on the current language. If the file doesn't exist, Joomla! will just skip that file.

```
JOOMLA/templates/mytheme/language/en-GB/en-GB.custom.ini
JOOMLA/templates/mytheme/language/fr-FR/fr-FR.custom.ini
JOOMLA/templates/mytheme/language/de-DE/de-DE.custom.ini
```

This makes it possible to make any changes to language-strings, without making any core hack. Very nice.

### Understanding the bootstrap

When overloading language-files, it is important to understand the Joomla! bootstrap: The language-loader will load any language-file that is not yet loaded. So if the core language-file is loaded after your own version, it will actually overwrite your own changes back to default. For instance, the template-code is executed before the actual modules are called. This means that you have to manually call the original language-file before calling your own.

For instance, if we want to override the language-file for mod_poll, the code to use is the following:

```
$language =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('mod_poll'); // this loads the original
$language->load('mod_poll', dirname(__FILE__), $language->getTag(), true); // this loads our own version
```

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: The problem is that when I want to get the selected language it return alway en-GB .``

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you try to access the language class outside the application, it will not work (it will always return the default language). You might have to instantiate the application. See this question for more infos : https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/function-getlanguage-does-not-return-current-language

Comment: Hi Simon, I show this question but adding 
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
Didn't change anything

Comment: And my default language is FR

Comment: Another solution is provided here : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/7204/5798 Seems like language detection in external scripts in Joomla 3 is a pain !

Comment: I try something like that by parsing the url with JURI to catch the /en/ or /fr/ in the url, but I never get this string with JURI it return the "simplified url" even if SEO is enabled or not.

Comment: Elin. I put fr as metakey in the menu that call my php script, however reading the metakey of active menu give nothing !!! I think Joomla 3 have some problems with external php scripts.

Comment: Well why not write a plugin to load the script and then it won't be external?

Comment: I find the way to get the language tag in the url by :

    // load language string definitions in url
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $app->initialise();
   $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
   $url = getenv("HTTP_REFERER");
   $choice_lg = strpos($url_lg, "/en/");
   if ($choice_lg === false) $lg_tag = "fr-FR";
  else $lg_tag = "en-GB";
  $extension = 'ed3c_soutenance';
  $base_dir = JPATH_SITE;
  $lang->load($extension, $base_dir, $lg_tag, true);